# Как изменить фрагмент адреса

Tags: php, .htaccess

Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить адрес при помощи htaccess?
Есть путь

```
http://site.ru/list/uml/home
```

Как сделать чтобы можно было открывать просто

```
http://site.ru/home
```

и получать содержимое

```
list/uml/home
```

`RewriteRule ^home list/uml/home [L]` 
не получается!

Comment: RewriteRule ^list/uml/home$ /home [L] ?

Answer (score 1):

уже 100 лет с Апачем не работал, но так вроде:

```
RewriteRule ^/home$ /list/uml/home
```

будет правильнее

Comment: спасибо, только выходит что при переходе на  http://site.ru/home меня перебрасывает все равно на http://site.ru/list/uml/home а я хотел бы чтобы было при переходе на http://site.ru/home отображалось содержимое http://site.ru/list/uml/home